# jquery: dblclick link call - browser back button doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, double-click

hey guys,
what am i doing wrong. i have kind of folders on my website that work with a doubleclick.
However somehow my window.location.replace doesn't kind of trigger the browser history.

if i use normal click without prevent default, i can use the browser back button. 
however as soon as i use the script underneath and i doubleclick on a folder i cannot use the browser back button.

```
$('.folder a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('.folder a').dblclick(function(e) {
    window.location.replace($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) says the replace wont add to history.

Try:

```
window.location.href =$(this).attr("href");
```